# MySQl Query which with a time tolerance

Tags: mysql, date, time

Hi so I have a query like so

```
SELECT
meteor_events.event_id AS event_id,
meteor_events.user_ID AS user_ID,
meteor_events.date AS date,
meteor_events.Time
from `meteor_events`
```

there may be multiple events for a given date ie

```
37775   2   2017-01-01  00:01:23
33500   1   2017-01-01  01:07:56
37776   2   2017-01-01  01:08:45
47827   3   2017-01-01  01:08:30
37777   2   2017-01-03  01:09:44
```

I want to update the query so it brings back a record where

1 - the dates match
and
2 - the times match but with a tolerance of 30 seconds either way

so in this example it would return

```
37776   2   2017-01-01  01:08:45
47827   3   2017-01-01  01:08:30
```

Im just not sure were to start ?

John B

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Possibly easier if you merge data and Time columns as one. Also avoid to use SQL keywords as column name

And you need a self join for the task:

```
SELECT a.event_id, a.user_ID, a.`date`, a.`Time`
FROM meteor_events AS a
JOIN meteor_events AS b
WHERE a.event_id != b.event_id
AND a.`date` = b.`date`
AND time_to_sec(a.`Time`) - time_to_sec(b.`Time`) BETWEEN -30 AND 30;
```

[image]

Comment: SIDU works well, it was quite slow so I added an index to the date and time columns and not speed is not an issue - it needs to be updated a little. If user 3 for instance has 2 matching dates and 2 times within + or - 30 seconds those results are returned as well, each user event is unique and user 3 could have several events only separated by a few seconds but they are unique events, I only want the query to bring back matching events from other users - hope this makes sense ?

Comment: In this case, add this: AND a.user_ID != b.user_ID

Comment: "Also avoid to use SQL keywords as column name" - Now tell me why? I have the "`" character. And it IS NOT making my queries too long